# Why do these green stripes appear when rendering with EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render an imported file (.obj) from FaceGen (https://facegen.com).

With EEVEE I have the following results:

[image: evee rendering]

But with CYCLES:

[image: Cycles render]

Why? 
I need to render with EEVEE, 
because it’s faster and I don’t need a high quality rendering.

Comment: is your gpu compatible with blender? are the drivers updated?

Comment: I dont know, this is my computer spec:

Processor  : AMD E2-1800 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Memory (RAM)  : 3619MB
OS : Ubuntu 19.04
OpenGL  : AMD PALM (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.0.0-25-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)

Comment: I don't know much about how to fix these problems. I only know that weird results can happen if you don't have a supported graphics card :|

Comment: The E2-1800 onboard GPU is a Radeon HD 7340, which is a Terrascale architecture GPU. These are not supported for Eevee. See https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/